# Bootstrap 3 Column Wrapping - Take up the available space in a column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am struggling a bit with how to get things lined up properly with Bootstrap 3. When a column wraps, I would like it to scroll up to the bottom of the last div.

Often times, I will have a sidebar which exceeds the length of the main body. The information which goes in the side bar is less important than the main box, but more important than the information on the bottom.

How can I get the two green sections in the following example to line up on a larger screen?

**View Example Code** -
http://www.bootply.com/42XM6PGoDS

```css
.example{
    background-color: green;
    min-height:200px
      
  }
  
.example2{
  background-color: red;
  min-height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="example">
        Main Body of Information
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="example2">
        Important information on sidebar when on a large screen
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="example">
        Less important information
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to simply use `pull-right` on the sidebar. This will allow the 2nd column to stay on the right.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="example">
        Main Body of Information
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right">
      <div class="example2">
        Important information on sidebar when on a large screen
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="example">
        Less important information
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/IGLRYDnc2S

Comment: This is where I ended up myself, it produces exactly what I want on a larger screen, but now if you're on a smaller screen, that column will no longer re-size. This is visible in the example.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating your main page with 2 columns (like col-*-9 and col-*-3) where the col-3 is for the sidebar. Then everything you add in the main page won't have the gap that you're talking about...

example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <!-- Main page content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!-- Sidebar content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The order that they are in when on a phone is important. It would need to be:

Green
Red
Green

Adding two columns, if I'm not mistaken, would end with Green Green Red

Comment: my bad, I can't think of anything off the top of my head in order to do that without javascript...

Comment: No problem, I'm stumped myself. This seems like it should be possible. I can get the proper effect on a large screen if I float the smaller column with pull-right. However, if the window is re-sized, it wont responsively change.

Comment: Maybe use a float-right in addition to hidden-xs, or visible-md, etc....then you'd have to define that sidebar section twice for the two scenarios though

Comment: That will work, and is a valid solution, but as a last resort. I dislike the redundancy with sending the same information twice with such a small change between them. There is a fairly substantial amount of information in the sidebar. It would be a lot of data to double up on. If there is no other option I'll accept that as the answer, but I really am hoping I don't have to.

Comment: Yep, I use that as my last possible approach when I have to use javascript...(and don't want to use javascript)